# How can hide a row if a condition is not met by access check?

Tags: views

I have overrided the `UserAccessControlHandler` class to fit my needs: some user can not be seen by some other users.

How to create a view listing only the users which can be "viewed" by the user looking at this view? [Could be nice to use `UserAccessControlHandler::checkAccess` to filter it]

I don't think that using `hook_views_pre_render` is good idea (pagination issue and it will be very slow), but maybe I am wrong or this is the only way.

**Edit to add**: This is a 'field' view displaying several fields of each user.

Comment: Maybe this module could work as a starter for your case https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_access

Comment: @Davis Thomas: I don't understand how this module will help me to filter view by access. As explained in the OP, I overrode `UserAccessControlHandler` which is what I could gain by using `reference_access`